# Does microphone recording volume has anything to do with background noise?

Tags: microphone, audacity

I am using a condenser mic with a Mac Book Pro. There are some noise outside the room. Which one is better recording volume? 50% or 100% to get less noise after final production?

I will apply compression and normalize for final production. It is a voice recording. So with 50% less noise will be captured and will be boosted with final production?

Or with 100% less noise in final production?

Answer (score 1):

Changing the input volume can never do anything to reduce extraneous noise being picked up by the mic.
If you turn it up or down, the noise will change by exactly the same amount as the signal.

You need to either separate it first -  by damping the source; at worst heavy curtains, at best double-thickness walls…
or change the relative distances - get the mic closer to you, which will make it relatively louder compared to the background.

Your final attack strategy is either expensive noise reduction software, or a more simple noise-gate or expander.
Either of these will only be useful against 'general murmur' & not help if, for instance, you have a dog barking in the background.